# How do Bayes nets simplify things?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

I recently came across **bayes networks**. I read that they help in **reducing the dimensionality** of the joint probability distribution of n random variables (let them be boolean).

```
In General
P(X1,X2,X3,.....Xn) = P(X1)*P(X2|X1)*P(X3|X1,X2)*.......*P(Xn|X1,X2,X3,.....Xn-1)
```

And Bayes network helps in simplifying the formula as it contains information about what variables actually depend on each other. This much I get.

What I don't get is how is it reducing the computations required to compute the probabilities?
Basically I don't understand the concept of dimensionality in context of joint distributions.

Comment: A naive bayes network will generally have reduced dimensionality, as it assumes independence in the feature set.

Comment: It simplifies based on conditional independence: `Prob(Rain | Wind, Traffic) = Prob(Rain | Wind)` since rain and traffic have not to do with each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the answer. 
It doesn't actually reduce the computations. It just reduces the space complexity.
This is a stub from wikipedia:

Using a Bayesian network can save considerable amounts of memory, if the dependencies i the joint distribution are sparse. For example, a naive way of storing the conditional probabilities of 10 two-valued variables as a table requires storage space for 2^{10} = 1024 values. If the local distributions of no variable depends on more than 3 parent variables, the Bayesian network representation only needs to store at most 10*2^3 = 80 values.
    One advantage of Bayesian networks is that it is intuitively easier for a human to understand (a sparse set of) direct dependencies and local distributions than complete joint distribution.

Comment: It also provides the prerequisites for reducing the computational cost: It tells how the problem can be structured (factorized).